# LLL and factoring polynomials in $\Bbb Z[x]$

Tags: polynomials, algorithms, computer-science, computational-mathematics, irreducible-polynomials

Given a degree $2k$ reducible polynomial $f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{2k}a_ix^i\in\Bbb Z[x]$ with $gcd(a_{2k},\dots,a_0)=1$ that is known to be of the form $f_1(x)f_2(x)$ with $deg(f_i(x))=\frac{deg(f(x)}{2}=k$ and each $f_i(x)$ irreducible.

Can LLL algorithm be used to factor $f(x)$ in polynomial time and what is the complexity?